# Importing button and text field from another class to main class

Tags: java, swing, object, nullpointerexception, jbutton

I have two different classes (`mainClass`) and (`visual`). In the visual class I have a method and inside the method I put the required code for a simple `JButton`. In the main class I create an object to call the method from visual class, to show the button in the main class . But it does not work. I would appreciate any advice.

```
package init;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class mainClass {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mainClass window = new mainClass();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public mainClass() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);


 In the code below I made an object and called the method from the visual class

        visual bt = new visual();
        bt.btn();

    }

}
```

////////////////VISUAL CLASS//////////////////////

```
package init;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class visual {
    public JFrame frame;

    public void btn() {

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(141, 155, 151, 45);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail what "doesn't work" means here?  What are you expecting to see and what do you actually see instead?

Comment: Also, never use `setBounds` and a null layout.  90% that's your problem right there.

Comment: The hole code does not work. The frame wont pup out at all.

Comment: Gentle reminder, this is a Q&A site, not a tutor site. I recommend reading through a Java tutorial such as [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/). Also please read through the entire [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also on the How To Ask page there's a link to MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Include one of those, your code looks incomplete and looks like it should throw NPE if actually executed.

Comment: @markspace Your premise is correct. The code as currently shown, throws an NPE. And a tip: `[mcve]` in a code comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Comment: OP: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) *"Sorry that my level of java knowledge is not high as you."* Spare us the insincere apologies. The advice offered by @xtratic was well intentioned & aimed at helping you to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to achieve here you don't need 2 classes. You can do it like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainClass {

  /**
   * Launch the application.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {

          JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
          frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
          frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
          frame.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```